# Install Mongo Tools from Source

Tags: mongodb, installation, mongoimport

I am installing MongoDB and I need mongoimport. I have installed MongoDB itself from source [MongoDB from source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source). I still need **mongoimport**, which is part of **mongo-tools** [mongo-tools github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools). Which states some instructions, I have cloned the repo, went into it (**/ssd/[MYNAME]/mongoinstall/mongo-tools**) and ran

```
. ./set_goenv.sh
```

The readme of the repo states to run `. ./set_gopath.sh` but this one doesn't exist.

Although I don't feel like the command did anything as
`go env` doesn't get changed.

I have installed GO from source as well.

```
go build -o bin/mongoimport mongoimport/main/mongoimport.go
```

returns the following error:

```
mongoimport/main/mongoimport.go:13:2: cannot find package "github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/log" in any of:
    /ssd/[MYNAME]/mongoinstall/go/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/log (from $GOROOT)
    /export/scratch1/home/gast141/go/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/log (from $GOPATH)
mongoimport/main/mongoimport.go:14:2: cannot find package "github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/signals" in any of:
    /ssd/[MYNAME]/mongoinstall/go/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/signals (from $GOROOT)
    /export/scratch1/home/gast141/go/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/signals (from $GOPATH)
mongoimport/main/mongoimport.go:15:2: cannot find package "github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/util" in any of:
    /ssd/[MYNAME]/mongoinstall/go/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/util (from $GOROOT)
    /export/scratch1/home/gast141/go/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools-common/util (from $GOPATH)
mongoimport/main/mongoimport.go:16:2: cannot find package "github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongoimport" in any of:
    /ssd/[MYNAME]/mongoinstall/go/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongoimport (from $GOROOT)
    /export/scratch1/home/gast141/go/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongoimport (from $GOPATH)
```

I have tried

```
./build.sh
```

but it exclaimes:

```
GOROOT not set and preferred GOROOT '/ssd/[MYNAME]/mongoinstall/go/bin/go' doesn't exist. Aborting.
```

The output of `go env` is:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/export/scratch1/home/gast141/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/export/scratch1/home/gast141/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/ssd/[MYNAME]/mongoinstall/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/ssd/[MYNAME]/mongoinstall/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build916816613=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I am on `Fedora release 28 (Twenty Eight)`

How can I get mongoimport to work?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into these same errors while trying to compile mongotools on a Mac system. In my case the issue is that `set_gopath.sh` (for version 3.6.5 of mongotools) is not compatible with the shell I use (`fish`). That script exports `GOPATH` environment variable but it does not appear to persist its appropriate variable once back in the `fish` environment.

I tried running `bash` to be in a persistent bash shell, running `set_gopath.sh` and then `go build` commands however the result was the same issue.

A successful workaround I have found is to modify `set_gopath.sh` and at the end include the `go build` commands. Running `set_gopath.sh` then sets up the environment and runs the go commands successfully.